# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0+} (\sin x)^x$

Tags: limits

I have tried to evaluate this by :--

$$(\sin x)^x = e^{(x \cdot \log (\sin x))} = (e^x)^{\log (\sin x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} (e^x)^{\log (\sin x)} = \lim_{ x \to 0+} e^{\log (\sin x)}(e^x-1)$$

But after this I couldn't proceed.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Note that $\sin x\approx x$ as $x\to0$ and use the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$.

Comment: @csch2 That's not really a rigorous argument.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @chsch2: you have to be careful when doing composition of equivalents of functions.

Comment: Only RHL exists. LHL does not exist

Answer (score 4):

Let $L=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}(\sin x)^x$. Then $\ln L=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x\ln(\sin x)=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{1/x}$. This puts the limit in a form to use L'Hopital's rule:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{1/x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x/\sin x}{-1/x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}-\frac{x^2\cos x}{\sin x}=-\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x\cos x$$
Using the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$ (this can be verified using the squeeze theorem), we get that $$-\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x\cos x=-1\cdot0\cdot1=0\implies \ln L=0$$
Now exponentiating:
$$\ln L=0\implies L=1$$
Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}(\sin x)^x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply L'Hopitals Rule twice.

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\left(\frac{\log (\sin x)}{1/x}\right)}$$

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^ {\left(\frac{-\cot x}{-1/x^2}\right)}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\left(\frac{x^2}{\tan x}\right)}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\left(\frac{2x}{(\sec x)^2}\right)}$$

$$= e^{0/1}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bit more than the limit itself, almost as you started, consider
$$y=\sin ^x(x)\implies \log(y)=x \log (\sin (x))$$ and use Taylor expansion
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
$$\log (\sin (x))=\log (x)-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\log(y)=x \log (x)-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{180}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=1+x \log (x)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(x)+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is based on hint from user csch2 (via comments to question) and IMHO is a simpler approach to the problem.

The expression under limit can be written as $$x^x\left(\frac{\sin x} {x} \right) ^x$$ and the second factor tends to $1^0=1$ so that the desired limit is equal to the limit of $x^x$ as $x\to 0^+$. This is easily handled by taking logs to get the expression $x\log x$ which tends to $0$ so that $x^x\to 1$.

That $x\log x\to 0$ is a well known fact on par with other well known limits like $\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}\to 1$.

Answer (score -1):

I like binomial expansions, so why not try one?

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin(x))^x & = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\tfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})^x \\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\tfrac{1}{(2i)^x}\sum_{k=0}^{x} {x\choose k} e^{ix(x-k)}(-e)^{-ix(k)} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{0} {0\choose k} e^{i0(0-k)}(-e)^{-i0(k)}\\
& = {0\choose 0} e^{0}(-1)^0e^{0}\\
& = 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How do you define $\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^x$?

Comment: Just as $\sum_{k=0}^{0}$. I'm not 100% this is valid (hence the "try" at the beginning). :)

Comment: I don't think this is valid. It is almost like writing the limit as  (sinx)^0=1

Comment: You're probably right. The definition at least makes sense to me, since if you take $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \cos(x)$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(x)$ (using their Taylor series), then the definition appears to work out.

If anything, maybe define it as being equal to the first term in the sum?

Comment: This has a fundamental problem as $x$ is a real variable and not necessarily a non-negative integer. You should edit to fix this. - 1 for now.

Comment: Feel free to suggest an edit. Your comment was not useful.

Comment: @JoeDriscoll If you *define* the symbol $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^x a_k(x)$ as the limit of the first term, $\lim_{x \to 0} a_0(x)$, then you need to justify your invocation of the binomial expansion, which is not proven to hold for your definition of the symbols.

Comment: @JoeDriscoll In fact, it's not difficult to come up with counterexamples. Given the "first term" definition, $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+e^{1/x})^x = e \neq 1 = \lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^x (1)^{x-k}(e^{1/x})^k$.

Comment: @jawheele Not sure why you think the right-hand side there is equal to 1. Your counterexample is problematic because you end up with a $e^{\tfrac{0}{0}}$. I'd think your example (based on my pretty bad definition) would evaluate to something like $\lim_{x,k\rightarrow 0}e^{\tfrac{k}{x}} = e$.

Comment: @JoeDriscoll The "first term" definition you suggested seems to be: consider only the $k=0$ term and take the limit of the resulting expression. The resulting expression in that case is $1^x=1$, the limit of which is $1$. Also, $\lim_{x,k \to 0} e^{\frac{k}{x}}$ is not well-defined. Along the path $k=2x$, for example, the expression limits to $e^2$.

Comment: @jawheele The "first term" definition was my alternative - I didnt give it much thought. I'll try to formalize what I'm thinking when I get home in a bit. I might have a neat proof that gets at what I'm saying.